# Apps Srcipt indexOf() not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, indexof

I am reading the body text of emails. You can check how the body appears in the photo attached.

I want to get the following substring: 'Current status- ROB2ReOnb". I am noticing that when the text I am looking for, is not on the same row, the indexOf gives me "-1". However, when is on the same row I can get a positive value for the indexOf.

My code is the following:

`current_status = body.substring(body.indexOf("Current status -"),body.indexOf("Active with App"))`

Do you know what can I be doing wrong? I am trying to spot the error for so long. Any tip/clue is more than welcome.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: could "Active" and "with" be separated by a newline maybe? `\n`

Comment: Thanks so much @Nick! I used the following code and it worked:                                   `help = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Active\nwith');
current_status_aux = body.substring(body.indexOf("Current status"),body.indexOf(help))`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer with @Nick Parsons comment:

```
help = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Active\nwith');
current_status_aux = body.substring(body.indexOf("Current status -"),body.indexOf(help))
```